Protect AdGuard DNS with mTLS
is it possible to Protected/Restrict Access to a AdGuard DNS (or any DNS for that matter) using mTLS?
I have a VPS with Traefik, AdGuard and EJBCA running. I already secure most of my Services with mTLS, but all of them are HTTP Services (Websites). Does this also "just work" with TCP/UDP based Services?
With Traefik, i just configured it with [tls.options.mTLSEnabled.clientAuth] thats used by the protected Services.
